# Django: Cannot access variable set in middleware

Tags: django, django-middleware

I am trying to add a variable to my request variable in my custom middleware. Later I want to access that variable from my view. Here are the relevant bits:

**middleware.py**

```
class DomainInterceptMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.myvar = 'whatever'
```

**settings.py** - Added this above `CommonMiddleware`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'page.middleware.DomainInterceptMiddleware',  #
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    output = request.myvar
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

However, on trying to access `/index`, I get this error

```
  File "/path/to/views.py", line 32, in index
    output = request.myvar
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'myvar'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current middleware class is written for the old `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.

You are using the `MIDDLEWARE` setting, so you need to write a [new-style middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/) (Django 1.10+).

If you need backwards compatibility, you could use the [`MiddlewareMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware) from `django.utils.deprecation`.

```
from django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin

class DomainInterceptMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.myvar = 'whatever'
```

Or you can convert it to a new-style middleware.

```
class DomainInterceptMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.myvar = 'whatever'
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

See the docs on [writing your own middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) for more info.